# Enviar parametros de la vista al controlador Con angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
DropDownList
```

fue creado por el framework

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdPais", null, "Seleccione un país", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "SelectPais", onchange = "SelPais()" })
```

este forma me envia el id que necesito al controlador.
el problema es de como enviar cuando utilizo angular ?

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDepa" onchange="SelDepa()">
        <option value="">seleccione Departamento</option>
        <option ng-repeat="item in myDataDepa" ng-value="item.IdDepartamento">{{item.Nombre}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

mi controlador

```
  public ActionResult Imprimir(Parameters parametros)
        {
//**
}
```

mi modelo

```
public class Parameters
    {
        public int IdPais { get; set; }
        public int IdDepartamento { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: angularjs y angular4 no es lo mismo. Pudieras especificar cual de los 2 exactamente?

Comment: exactamento  `AngularJS v1.0.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la directiva [`ngOptions`](http://cursoangularjs.es/doku.php?id=unidades:04_masdirectivas:05_ngoptions) para asignar los valores a un select. A esto se le asigna un `ngModel` que se le asignara el objeto del valor seleccionado en el `select`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $http){

  $scope.myDataDepa = [
    { IdDepartamento: 1, Nombre: "Departamento 1" },
    { IdDepartamento: 2, Nombre: "Departamento 2" },
    { IdDepartamento: 3, Nombre: "Departamento 3" }
  ];
  
  $scope.departamento = {};
  $scope.guardar = function(){
    console.log($scope.departamento);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-options="departamento.Nombre for departamento in myDataDepa" ng-model="departamento">
    </select>
    
    <input type="button" ng-click="guardar()" value="Guardar" />
</div>
```

Nota como al presionar guardar se imprime el valor seleccionado. Ahora solo tendrias que enviar esos valores por ajax utilizando el servicio `$http`. Por ejemplo:

```
$http.post("url", $scope.departamento).success(function(response){
   // respuesta del servidor.
});
```

Comment: estoy probando ahora mismo

Comment: @Einer me podes ayudar con este tema porfavor!!!, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134470/mostrar-varios-componentes-con-angular